# Repeat name for each time an element appears in parent XML node

Tags: xml, r, xpath

Here is a simplified version of an XML file I'm trying to parse in R using the `XML` package:

```
testXML<-
'<MYDOC>
  <PARENT>
    <NAME>A</NAME>
    <COUNTTHIS>blah</COUNTTHIS>
    <COUNTTHIS>blah</COUNTTHIS>
  </PARENT>
  <PARENT>
    <NAME>B</NAME>
    <COUNTTHIS>blah</COUNTTHIS>
  </PARENT>
  <PARENT>
    <NAME>C</NAME>
    <COUNTTHIS>blah</COUNTTHIS>
    <COUNTTHIS>blah</COUNTTHIS>
    <COUNTTHIS>blah</COUNTTHIS>
  </PARENT>
</MYDOC>'
```

I would like to grab the `NAME` value in each `PARENT` node, repeated by the number of times that `COUNTTHIS` appears within `PARENT`.  I would also like the running count of `COUNTTHIS` within `PARENT`.  So the desired output would be a data frame like this:

```
# Name  ID
#    A   1
#    A   2
#    B   1
#    C   1
#    C   2
#    C   3
```

I've got something that works, but it seems like there should be a better way.  I'm going to be parsing lots of XML files, so I'd like to make sure it's efficient.

```
library(XML)

parsedXML <- xmlTreeParse(testXML, useInternalNodes=T)

cnt <- unlist(getNodeSet(parsedXML, "//NAME", fun=xmlValue))

names <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(cnt)) {names[i] <- length(getNodeSet(parsedXML, paste0("//PARENT[NAME='",cnt[i],"']/COUNTTHIS")))}

rep(cnt, times=names)
#[1] "A" "A" "B" "C" "C" "C"
```

(Note that I'm not bothering to add the ID column here, since I already know how to do that.  But please feel free to include that step in your answer, since you may have a better method for that too.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks pretty good, but here is a slightly simplified version that uses `sapply` to save you from having to use `unlist` and the `for`-loop.

```
cnt <- xpathSApply(parsedXML,'//NAME', xmlValue, simplify=TRUE)
names <- sapply(cnt, function(i)
           length(xpathApply(parsedXML, paste0("//PARENT[NAME='",i,"']/COUNTTHIS"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use xmlToList here

```
x <- xmlToList(parsedXML)
y <- sapply(x, function(y) rep(y[["NAME"]], sum(names(y) == "COUNTTHIS")))
data.frame(Name = unlist(y), ID = unlist(sapply(y,  seq) ))
  Name ID
1    A  1
2    A  2
3    B  1
4    C  1
5    C  2
6    C  3
```